# Redirecting output to a file also includes the name of the file I'm redirecting to?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, scripting, redirect

I'm using a simple directory command
I have one file in the directory

```
   C:\tokyo\scripts\notempty>dir /b /a-d
```

1.pst

So far so good

When I redirect the result into a file

```
    C:\tokyo\scripts\notempty>dir /b /a-d > test
```

I get this

```
     C:\tokyo\scripts\notempty>type test
     1.pst
     test
```

Question:  Why does the name of the file I'm creating ( test ) ends up in the file ?
           The file should only contain 1.pst.

Can someone please help. This is driving me nuts.

Thanks 
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the file `dir` executes the file `test` is already initialized by the shell (command.com/cmd.exe) to be opened for redirected output and that's the reason why `dir` sees it as well. If it's not the shell then it's probably a lower level system like DOS itself but the concept is similar.

Comment: Thanks .. So How do I get around this?

Comment: I just want to have the file name in directory in the output file.

Comment: @mattbeyond You can redirect it to another directory or place it there first then move the file back e.g. `dir /a-d /b >c:\temp\test & move c:\temp\test .` In the old days of DOS, `c:\temp` is the common temporary directory. You can create it if you don't have it.

Comment: Another way actually is to use `find /v` but other matches could be excluded as well with it. The one I told is the cleaner method.

Comment: Ok thx - I get it. The first solution u suggested works .. I'm just thinking there must be a better way of redirecting a list of files one has in a directory to a file without creating a temp file. I do not have this issue in under unix os. Any suggestion please?

Comment: wondering if there is VB script that can manage this without creating a temp fodler

Comment: Well the other, you could use find: `dir | find /v "test" > test`

Comment: Yeah - Ok - I give up .. I go with the second solution as I have to run this script in few hosts and I do not want to create any temp folders .. Still this is really horrible that this is how it works